# Migrated to Swift 3 - Getting the following error during URL Session

Tags: swift, session, swift3, nsurl

On Xcode 7 (and Swift 2), the following code worked fine. What it does is take a weather API json string of current observations, and then I parse the string and locate the UV value. (I know it's messy but I just couldn't get my head around JSON parsing). Don't mind me splitting up the string into smaller and smaller arrays. What is wrong is at the bottom of the code snippet:

```
class weatherGetter {
    fileprivate let weatherMapBaseURL = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/"
    fileprivate let weatherAPIKey = "************"

    func getWeather(city: String) {
        // This is a pretty simple networking task, so the shared session will do.
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let weatherRequestURL = URL(string: "\(weatherMapBaseURL)\(weatherAPIKey)/conditions/q/FL/\(city).json")!

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherRequestURL, completionHandler: {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
            if let error = error {
                // Case 1: Error
                // We got some kind of error while trying to get data from the server.
                print("Error:\n\(error)")
            }
            else {
                do {
                    // Try to convert that data into a Swift dictionary
                    let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print("Human-readable data:\n\(dataString!)")
                    let fullArr = dataString!.characters.split{$0 == "\n"}.map(String.init)

                    let smallArr = String(fullArr[79]).characters.split{$0 == ":"}.map(String.init)

                    let smallerArr = String(smallArr[1]).characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
                    //let smallerArr2 = String(smallArr[1]).characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
                    //let characters = Array(smallerArr)
                    //print(smallerArr[0])
                    let final = String(smallerArr[0])
                    //print(final)
                    let charArr = Array(final!.characters)
                    //print(charArr)
                    let subarray = charArr[1...charArr.count-2]
                    let finalNum = String(subarray)
                    let myDouble = Double(finalNum)
                    var myDouble2: Double = myDouble!
                    print(myDouble2)
                    Calculator_Calculations.sharedInstance.uvIndex = myDouble2
                    print(Calculator_Calculations.sharedInstance.uvIndex)
                    //print(String(subarray))
                    //print(finalNum)
                    //print(myDouble)
                }
                // Case 2: Success
                // We got a response from the server!
                //let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                //print("Human-readable data:\n\(dataString!)")
            }
        } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)

        // The data task is set up...launch it!
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

When I migrate to Swift 3 I get the following error for this line of code

```
}as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)
```

> exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

I know this has something to do with nil values etc. but I'm new enugh to Swift and ever since I migrated to Swift 3 I'm having numerous problems sorting my code out.

Answer (score 1):

I removed NS from NSError and changed it just to Error and code ran fine.

Comment: thanks for sharing, such an easy fix relieved so much stress =)